# TTouchKeyboard: send keystroke to other program?

Tags: delphi, virtual-keyboard

How do I use TTouchKeyboard in Delphi, so it could send keystrokes to other program. For example, I want to type password in a browser using TTouchKeyboard component. I have no idea how make the browser stay focus while I'm clicking on my keyboard.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`TTouchKeyboard` sends the keys to the current control focused: so if you have a `TEdit` with the **focus**, the TEdit will receive the key...

You can create a form which contains the `TTouchKeyboard` and add this procedure:

```
  protected
    procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override;

...

procedure TForm1.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited CreateParams(Params);
  with Params do
  begin
    ExStyle   := ExStyle or WS_EX_NOACTIVATE;
    WndParent := GetDesktopwindow;
  end;
end;
```

Your form can't have the focus... so, the key is sent to the previous focused control. (I have just tested it and it works: the key has been sent to this webpage)

Comment: Bingo! WS_EX_NOACTIVATE is what I need.

Comment: This does not seem to work for me, in that the control loses the focus when I press on a key on the virtual keyboard. What am I missing? I'm using XE2 in this case.