# TTouchKeyboard: send keystroke to same program?

Tags: delphi, key, send

I saw your tip about : [TTouchKeyboard: send keystroke to other program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509704/ttouchkeyboard-send-keystroke-to-other-program)

How can I send the keys to the other form in the same Delphi application?

And how can I call the form with the TTouchKeyboard? (Show, showModal, parameters?)

Thanks!

Comment: What tip are you talking about? Links, please.

Answer (score 1):

ShowModal is a bad idea... you focus the caller...

You can still use the same tip with the form which contains the keyboard, in order to stay disable...

Then, you can add a property with the handle of the form which should get the keystroke.

And finally, you hack the `TTouchKeyboard` to set the focus to the form with the handle you previously set...

For instance, your `TTouchKeyboard` hack could be like this:

```
type
  TMyKeyboard = class(TTouchKeyboard)
  protected
    procedure WndProc(var Message: TMessage); override;
  end;
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
```

...

```
  private
    fHandleOfTheTargetForm: HWND;
  public
    property HandleOfTheTargetForm: HWND read fHandleOfTheTargetForm write fHandleOfTheTargetForm;
```

...

```
procedure TMyKeyboard.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  if (Assigned(Form1)) then
  begin
    if Form1.HandleOfTheTargetForm <> 0 then
    begin
      SetForegroundWindow(HandleOfTheTargetForm);
    end;
  end;
  inherited;
end;
```

You can find a quick demo project [here](http://www.whiler.com/delphi/keyboard.zip).

Comment: Hi Whiler, I try the tips above, but don´t work. Can I send to you a little project by mail, or you send me a project that are working ? My email jean@odypark.com.br, thanks a lot !

Comment: @JeanAlysson: I have added a link at the end of my answer with a demo project.

Comment: Ok, thanks by help me, but are there how call the KeyboardForm with button click, retrieve the content and set in the target form and close it when I need ?